# Google Maps API:  find a route between two points in Israel

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to find a route between two points i enter manually at my html page but i get ZERO_RESULTS return value.

The users enters two locations  src_address = "Tel Aviv" and dst_address = "Haifa".

i get their geometric location by calling geocoder.geocode twice for each address. then set :
src_latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
dst_latlng = results[0].geometry.location;

however, when asking for router i get ZERO_RESULTS:

here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<img src="globe123.jpg" width="72" height="75"/> 
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var geodesic;
  var poly;
  var src_latlng;
  var dst_latlng;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


    var polyOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    }
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    // Add a listener for the click event
    //google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLocation);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var src_address = document.getElementById("SRC_ADDR").value;
    var dst_address = document.getElementById("DST_ADDR").value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': src_address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(results[0].geometry.location);
        src_latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': dst_address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(8);

        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(results[0].geometry.location);
        dst_latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });


        calcRoute();

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });



  }

  function calcRoute() {



      var start = src_latlng;
      var end = dst_latlng;
      var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end ,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };

      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {         
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        } else {
            alert(status);            
        }    
        });
    }


</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">


  <div style="text-align:left">
  Source: <input id="SRC_ADDR" type="textbox" value="Tel-Aviv, Israel">
  Destination: <input id="DST_ADDR" type="textbox" value="Haifa, Israel">
  <input type="button" value="Calculate Travel Time" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:40%;width:40%;top:120px"></div>
  <!-- <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div> 
  -->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am not sure, but it looks like the issue is causes when source and destination are out of the USA!

Comment: i have added a full code of the html page.

Comment: i did that. sorry i didn't notice that i should accept. i am kind of new to stackoverflow. now i am doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google doesn't have Maps API coverage for Israel yet, hence the ZERO_RESULTS status returned from the `directionsService.route` function call.

See Google's map coverage details worksheet of supported regions [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#whatcountries).  The direct link to the spreadsheet is [here](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html).

Comment: Indeed, Israel isn't there. however, why searching in maps.google.com is working for israel?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, actually.  :)

Answer (score 2):

hi you can use this code to get route between souurce and destinations

```
function setRoute()
{
      var fromAddress=document.getElementById("txtfromAddress").value;
      var toAddress=document.getElementById("txttoAddress").value; 
      if(fromAddress!="" && toAddress!="")
      {
       if(!fromAddress && !toAddress)
       {
       alert('ROute not found');
       }
       GDir1.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress);        


      }
      else
      {
        alert('Route Directions Required');
      }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this still not working for Israel maps. Looks like google maps don't support Israel in the API

Answer (score 0):

***http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html***
see if it covers your region it includes detailed view of street view or satellite view etc available or not
 GL